# Why does an empty Android ICS app almost occupy all the heap size?

Tags: android, heap-memory

I am developing a game application under Android built for SDKs >= 8. I always tested it under an Android 2.2 phone and never had a problem. When I moved to a Nexus phone with ICS mounted on I started having problems with the heap memory allocation. I tried to remove everything in the app to see where I was having memory leak problems or strange allocations (using both DDMS and MAT under Eclipse) until I decided to just start an empty activity and to do nothing more.

Under Android 2.2 the heap size at startup is about 2.0MB, while under Android 4.1 is about 11MB. Why is there such a great difference?

More, when I play my app the heap size on ICS, the garbage collector quickly starts freeing memory and the whole application becomes slow and with a very low FPS. Under Android 2.2 everything is really smooth and clean, without any single problem.

Does anyone can suggest me where's the difference between these two systems? I don't want to talk about my app implementation (I already spent 2 weeks optimizing code, memory allocation and retention and everything else. Can't do much more), but I want to understand where all that memory goes just at app startup. Also, ICS seems to require much more memory to load and retain bitmaps and drawables.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Has this been resolved?

Comment: Nope. It is still an open question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I may be late to the party, but I figured out the root of your (and my) problem.

Before Android 3.0 (not sure if this was in the entire 1.x/2.x series) all bitmap related memory was not stored on the heap. So with 3.0 they started locating everything on the heap. I am not sure why an empty application takes up 11MB, I can only guess it is related to the default Android bitmaps used in applications.

Now there is another problem: in earlier versions of Android, there was only a 'drawable' folder, not a 'drawable-hdpi', 'drawable-mdpi' etc... folder. For some reason, when loading in a image from the 'drawable' folder, it takes up HUGE amounts of space. The solution is to add different resolution variants of your images to *all* the drawable-Xdpi (where X is l,m,h or xh) folders. It reduced my starting heap size from around 26MB to a good 16MB. Even if you don't resize them, and just copy-paste them into the folders, it will still result in quite a significant change in Bitmap sizes.

I hope I help some people by posting this.

-Z